# Definition of Cell Decomposition?

Tags: general-topology, definition, geometric-topology, cw-complexes

In Chapter 5 of Lee's Intro to Topological Manifolds (page 130), he defines a cell decomposition as follows:

[image]

I've been struggling to properly unpack this characterization. I have the two following confusions.

a) When he says the map $\phi:D\to X$ such that $\phi|_{\mathrm{Int}D}$ is a homeomorphism between $\mathrm{Int} D$ and $e$, I'm not sure what exactly is the interior of $D$, as $D$ is simply some topological space that is homeomorphic to a closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, in a sense, wouldn't $\mathrm{Int}D= D$ because $D$ is open in $D$ itself? But of course this doesn't make much sense.

b) When Lee says $\phi$ maps $\partial D$ into the union of all cells of $\mathcal{E}$ of dimensions strictly less than $n$, which of the following does he mean?
$$\Phi(\partial D) \subseteq \bigcup_{e\in \mathcal{E}'}e\text{ such that }\mathcal{E}' = \{e\in \mathcal{E}:\text{dimension of }e\text{ is}<n\}$$
$$\Phi(\partial D)  = \bigcup_{e\in \mathcal{E}''}e\text{ such that }\mathcal{E}'' \subseteq \mathcal{E}'\text{ where }\mathcal{E}'\text{ is as defined above}$$
$$\Phi(\partial D) = \bigcup_{e\in \mathcal{E}'}e\text{ where }\mathcal{E}'\text{ is as defined above}$$
Any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $a)$ $D$ is the the *closed* unit ball in some euclidean space. i.e. $D=D^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |x|\leq 1\}$. The interior is the open ball $D^n\setminus S^{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |x|<1\}$. $b)$ The first one (which is the same as the third one?)

Comment: Ok that seems to make sense, any ideas on the boundaries of D?

Comment: Fix a homeomorphism $D^n\cong D$, where $n$ is the dimension of the cell $e$, so we can work with $D^n$. The boundary of $D^n$ is $\partial D^n=S^{n-1}$. The map $\phi$ should now map $S^{n-1}$ into $X_{n-1}=\bigcup_{\dim e<n}e$ and restrict to a homeomorphism of $int(D^n)=D^n\setminus S^{n-1}$ onto the open cell $e\subseteq X$.

Comment: The best way to get the idea is to look at an example. $S^1$ has a cell decomposition with one $0$-cell and one $1$-cell. It has a different cell decomposition with two $0$-cells and two $1$-cells. If you can work out what these are you'll have a pretty good idea of how things are meant to work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Note that I explained these uses of the notations $\partial D$ and $\operatorname{Int} D$ on page 129, in the paragraph just before the subsection heading. It says there that if $D$ is a closed $n$-cell, then $\partial D$ and $\operatorname{Int} D$ denote the images of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ and ${\mathbb B}^n$, respectively, under some homeomorphism $F\colon \overline {\mathbb B}{}^n \to D$.

(b) Your first interpretation is correct (as is your third; I don't see any difference between them). The union of all cells of dimension less than $n$ is a subset of $X$, and the requirement is just that $\Phi(\partial D)$ be contained in that subset. It doesn't say anything about the image being equal to the entire subset or being equal to a union of cells.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the third to fix a typo, so my first interpretation is correct in that case.